# How to assign a value to a key within an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to add the about, link values into the description array defined in the schema and then use the `.save()` function to save it to the database. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

```js
router.post('/:name/description',async(req, res)=>{
    const project = await Project.findOne({name: req.params.name})

    if (!project) {
        return res.status(404).send('project doesn\'t exist. Check URL');
    } else { 
        const {about, link} = req.body.description;
        console.log(project);
    }
});
```

Schema:

```js
const projectSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    main_image: {
        type: Buffer
    },
    description:[{ 
        about: {
            type: String
        },
        github_link: {
            type: String
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: `req.body.description` is an array, you need to index it or loop over it. E.g.. `req.body.description[0]`

Comment: There's no `link` property in the description, did you mean `github_link`?

Comment: What is your request body? Have you tried to loop over description array and get objects from it. Because the you destructing is imposible.

Comment: I'm trying to add the values from ``` const {about, link} = req.body.description; ``` and assign the 'about' value to the 'about' key in the schema and the 'link' value to the 'github_link' in the schema.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `push`:

```
router.post('/:name/description',async(req, res)=>{
    const project = await Project.findOne({name: req.params.name})

    if (!project) {
        return res.status(404).send('project doesn\'t exist. Check URL');
    } else { 
        const {about, link} = req.body.description;
        project.description.push({ about, github_link: link });
        await project.save();
        return res.status(201).send('Description added to project');
    }
});
```

Comment: This was perfect!! Thank you. I tried to do something with push but just couldn't figure out how to make it work. Thank you!!